# BLAS with a selected dimension in an array to utilize symmetry in individual tensor

Tags: arrays, fortran, blas

Related questions
[BLAS with symmetry in higher order tensor in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66633445/blas-with-symmetry-in-higher-order-tensor-in-fortran)

[How to speed up reshape in higher rank tensor contraction by BLAS in Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66253618/how-to-speed-up-reshape-in-higher-rank-tensor-contraction-by-blas-in-fortran/66256652#66256652)

To evaluate the following tensor contraction
`A[a,b] * B[b,c,d] = C[a,c,d]`
(Einstein summation rule implied, repeated indices, `b`, means summation.) with symmetries `B[b,c,d] = B[b,d,c]` and hence `C[a,c,d] = C[a,d,c]`. As suggested in the related question above,

```
do d=1,n
  do c=1,d
    C(:,c,d) = matmul(A(:,:), B(:,c,d))  !This block came from the answer in the first related question. I think it should be matmul(A(a,:), B(:,c,d))
  enddo
  
  do c=d+1,n
    C(:,c,d) = C(:,d,c)
  enddo
enddo
```

To utilize BLAS in `matmul`, it seems I need to do summation in some dimension of an array.  In using DGEMM, is there any way to specify the range of indices being used in the array `B`? By the size of `K` in stackoverflow.com/questions/66296334/openmp-with-blas? Should I account from the first index of `B`?

I tried to introduce smaller arrays, e.g., `B_small(:) = B(:,c,d), C_small(:) = C(:,c,d)`, manipulating new arrays take quite some time

An attempt to use `DGEMM` and `DGEMV`

```
Program blas_symm_tensor

  Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only :  wp => real64, li => int64

  Implicit None

  Real( wp ), Dimension( :, :    ), Allocatable :: a
  Real( wp ), Dimension( :, :, : ), Allocatable :: b
  Real( wp ), Dimension( :, :, : ), Allocatable :: c1, c2, c3, c4, c5

  Integer :: na, nb, nc, nd, ne
  Integer :: la, lb, lc, ld  
  Integer( li ) :: start, finish, rate, numthreads
  
  Write( *, * ) 'na, nb, nc, nd ?'
  Read( *, * ) na, nb, nc, nd
  
  ne = nc * nd
  
  Allocate( a ( 1:na, 1:nb ) ) 
  Allocate( b ( 1:nb, 1:nc, 1:nd ) ) 
  Allocate( c1( 1:na, 1:nc, 1:nd ) ) 
  Allocate( c2( 1:na, 1:nc, 1:nd ) ) 
  Allocate( c3( 1:na, 1:nc, 1:nd ) )
  Allocate( c4( 1:na, 1:nc, 1:nd ) )
  Allocate( c5( 1:na, 1:nc, 1:nd ) )
  
  ! Set up some data
  Call Random_number( a )
  Call Random_number( b )
  
  ! symmetrize tensor b
  do la = 1, na 
    do lc = 1, nc
      do ld = lc+1, nd
         b(la,lc,ld) = b(la,ld,lc)
      enddo
    enddo
  enddo
  
  Call System_clock( start, rate )
  c1 = 0.0_wp
  
  do ld = 1, nd  
    do lc = 1, nc
      do lb = 1, nb
        do la = 1, na    
          c1(la,lc,ld) = c1(la,lc,ld)  + a(la,lb) * b(lb, lc, ld)
        enddo  
      enddo
    enddo
  enddo  
 
  Call System_clock( finish, rate )
  Write( *, * ) 'Time for loop', Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate  
 
  Call System_clock( start, rate )
  c2 = 0.0_wp
  
  do ld = 1, nd  
    do lc = 1, ld
      do lb = 1, nb
        do la = 1, na    
          c2(la,lc,ld) = c2(la,lc,ld)  + a(la,lb) * b(lb, lc, ld)
        enddo  
      enddo
    enddo
  enddo  
 
  do ld = 1, nd  
    do lc = ld+1, nc 
      do la = 1, na     
        c2(la,lc,ld) = c2(la,ld,lc)
      end do  
    enddo
  enddo  

  Call System_clock( finish, rate )
  Write( *, * ) 'Time for symmetric loop', Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate  

  Call System_clock( start, rate )
  c3 = 0.0_wp
  
  do ld = 1, nd  
    do lc = 1, ld  
       Call dgemm( 'N', 'N', na, 1, nb, 1.0_wp, a , Size( a , Dim = 1 ), &
                                            b(:,lc,ld) , Size( b , Dim = 1 ), &
                                            0.0_wp, c3, Size( c3, Dim = 1 ) )      
    enddo
  enddo  
  
  do ld = 1, nd  
    do lc = ld+1, nc 
      do la = 1, na     
        c3(la,lc,ld) = c3(la,ld,lc)
      end do  
    enddo
  enddo  
  Call System_clock( finish, rate )
  
  Write( *, * ) 'Time for symmetric dgemm', Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate
  
  ! Direct
  Call System_clock( start, rate )
  Call dgemm( 'N', 'N', na, ne, nb, 1.0_wp, a , Size( a , Dim = 1 ), &
                                            b , Size( b , Dim = 1 ), &
                                            0.0_wp, c4, Size( c4, Dim = 1 ) )
  Call System_clock( finish, rate )
  Write( *, * ) 'Time for straight dgemm', Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate

  Call System_clock( start, rate )
  c5 = 0.0_wp
  do ld = 1, nd  
    do lc = 1, ld  
       Call dgemv( 'N', na,  nb, 1.0_wp,  a, na, b(1,lc,ld), 1, 0.0_wp,  c5, 1 )      
    enddo
  enddo  
   
  do ld = 1, nd  
    do lc = ld+1, nc 
      do la = 1, na     
        c5(la,lc,ld) = c5(la,ld,lc)
      end do  
    enddo
  enddo  
  Call System_clock( finish, rate )
  Write( *, * ) 'Time for symmetric dgemv', Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate
  
  do la = 1, na 
    do lc = 1, nc
      do ld = 1, nd
      
         if ( dabs(c1(la,lc,ld) - c2(la,lc,ld))  > 1.e-6 ) then 
           write (*,*) '!!! c2', la,lc,ld, c1(la,lc,ld) - c2(la,lc,ld)
         endif               
                  
         if ( dabs(c1(la,lc,ld) - c3(la,lc,ld))  > 1.e-6 ) then 
           write (*,*) '!!! c3', la,lc,ld, c1(la,lc,ld) - c3(la,lc,ld)
         endif         
 
         if ( dabs(c1(la,lc,ld) - c4(la,lc,ld))  > 1.e-6 ) then 
           write (*,*) '!!! c4', la,lc,ld, c1(la,lc,ld) - c4(la,lc,ld)
         endif        
 
         if ( dabs(c1(la,lc,ld) - c5(la,lc,ld))  > 1.e-6 ) then 
           write (*,*) '!!! c5', la,lc,ld, c1(la,lc,ld) - c5(la,lc,ld)
         endif   
 
      enddo
    enddo
  enddo  
  
End Program blas_symm_tensor
```

Got different number in `c3` and `c5` than naive nested loops :(

PS: There seems to be some tensor contraction with symmetry in Julia https://jutho.github.io/TensorKit.jl/stable/man/intro/
I am not sure the time in interacting with Julia from Fortran :(

Comment: Sorry, I am confused as to what you want to do. Is it Matmul( A, B( :, c, d ) ) for all c, d, or Matmul( A, B( c, :, d ) ), again for all c, d?

Comment: Sorry I did not express myself clearly. ```B(c,:,d)``` is another example, for ```A[a,b] * B[b,d,c] = C[a,d,c]```, I am wondering about specifying dimension in DGEMM. Maybe I should stick to ```A[a,b] * B[b,c,d] = C[a,c,d]``` and ```B(:,c,d)```. And, in the quoted pseudo code example, I think ```matmul(A(:,:), B(:,c,d))``` should be ```matmul(A(a,:), B(:,c,d))```

Comment: Well for the first case your earlier question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66253618/how-to-speed-up-reshape-in-higher-rank-tensor-contraction-by-blas-in-fortran/66256652#66256652 is precisely about that case

Comment: But, how to utilize your answer inside the nested loops of ```d``` and ```c```, in order to utilize the symmetries? I think your answer covered all indices :(

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that c goes from 1 to d. But that means you can get rid of the c loop and write it as Matmul( a, b( :, 1:d, d ) ) and then it's easy to write it as a loop over dgemms of increasing size.

Comment: Do you mean replace ```B``` in ```dgemm``` as ```B( :, 1:d, d ) ```? I shall try. Why not ```B( :, c d ) ```?