# Fast swap two dimension in an array in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran

Suppose I have a multi-dimension array in Fortran
`A(:,:,:,:)`, where the size of each dimension is the same, `n`.

I would like to swap the second and third dimension. I can do a reshape
`A2 = reshape(A, (/ n, n, n, n/), order = (/1,3,2,4/) )` 
Is there any faster way? Since I only need a partial swap.

Updated Example code

```
Program reshape_test

  Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only :  wp => real64, li => int64

  real :: A(32,32,32,32), A2(32,32,32,32)
  integer :: i,j,k,l,n,m, m_iter
  Integer( li ) :: start, finish, rate
  
  
  m_iter = 3200
  n = 32
  do l = 1, n
    do k = 1, n
       do j = 1, n
         do i = 1, n
           A(i,j,k,l) = i + j * k**2 - l
         end do 
       end do   
    end do      
  end do        
 
  Call System_clock( start, rate )
  do m=1,m_iter
    A2 = reshape(A, (/n, n, n, n/), order = (/1,3,2,4/) ) 
  end do
  
 ! write (*,*) A(1,2,3,4), A(1,3,2,4), A2(1,2,3,4), A2(1,3,2,4)
  Call System_clock( finish, rate )  
  
  Write(*,*) 'Time for reshape-1', Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate  
  
  
  Call System_clock( start, rate )
  do m=1,m_iter

  do j = 1, n
    do i = 1, n  
      A2(:,i,j,:) =  A(:,j,i,:)
    end do      
  end do      
  end do
  
  !write (*,*) A(1,2,3,4), A(1,3,2,4), A2(1,2,3,4), A2(1,3,2,4)
  Call System_clock( finish, rate )  
  
  Write(*,*) 'Time for reshape-2', Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate  
    
    
  Call System_clock( start, rate )
  do m=1,m_iter 
  do l = 1, n
    do k = 1, n
       do j = 1, n
         do i = 1, n
           A2(i,k,j,l) = A(i,j,k,l)
         end do 
       end do   
    end do      
  end do   
  end do
  
 ! write (*,*) A(1,2,3,4), A(1,3,2,4), A2(1,2,3,4), A2(1,3,2,4)
  Call System_clock( finish, rate )      
  
  Write(*,*) 'Time for reshape-3', Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate  
    
        

end program reshape_test
```

In this example, by  `gfortran -o3`, I got (I run three times)

```
 Time for reshape-1   13.500307800000000
 Time for reshape-2   10.146418400000000
 Time for reshape-3   20.489294800000000

 Time for reshape-1   11.421597100000000
 Time for reshape-2   9.3823936999999997
 Time for reshape-3   19.856221900000001

 Time for reshape-1   14.376207500000000
 Time for reshape-2   10.756465400000000
 Time for reshape-3   21.301044500000000
```

Adding `-march=native` leads to (I run three times)

```
 Time for reshape-1   12.517529200000000
 Time for reshape-2   10.240939200000000
 Time for reshape-3   26.637998799999998

 Time for reshape-1   12.436479700000000
 Time for reshape-2   9.9803838000000002
 Time for reshape-3   21.760061700000001

 Time for reshape-1   11.419214300000000
 Time for reshape-2   10.908747200000001
 Time for reshape-3   21.445951399999998
```

Overall approach 2 is the fastest. `-march=native`  seems not very effective.

(code style of report timing follows answer in [How to speed up reshape in higher rank tensor contraction by BLAS in Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66253618/how-to-speed-up-reshape-in-higher-rank-tensor-contraction-by-blas-in-fortran?noredirect=1#comment117134076_66253618))

Comment: `write(*,*) 'Time for reshape', Real(finish - start, wp) / rate  ` when the reshape is outside the timing determination? Also the initialization loop is a bit inefficient (see comment from Jack with the suggestion to check)

Comment: Sorry! My mistake

Comment: @AlphaF20 Note that gfortran throws an error because you have a typo. It is `-march=native` instead of `-martch=native` (arch like architecture).

Comment: I think you need to make the array bigger, or run each case a few thousand times to get more reliable numbers,  and take the write-statement out of the timing. These results could be random. It is strange that `-march=native` gives consistently worse timings.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to compare reshape with explicit loops like

```
do i = 1, n
  do j = 1, n
     do k = 1, n
       do l = 1, n
         A2(i,k,j,l) = A(i,j,k,l)
       end do 
     end do   
  end do      
end do
```

and then you tell us the answer. It could also depend on optimization. I would suggest `-O3 -march=native`, and try changing to `-O2`, `-O1` and `-O0`.

Comment: Is it not more efficient to loop over the `l` index first (column-major ordering)? Or do modern compiler optimize that themselves?

Comment: Optimisers might be able to sort out simple cases, but personally I would much prefer to do it myself - then I know it is right. And it's not any less readable

Comment: What about leaving out the explicit `i` loop altogether, i.e. `A2(:,k,j,l) = A(:,j,k,l)`?

Comment: Thanks. I will report in my question.

Comment: @jack In deed the loop order should be the opposite! I just copied from the question without checking. Using ":" instead of "i" is fine, but in this case I would not because then there is one more unknown.