# Best way of evaluating A[a,b] * B[c,b,d] = C[a,c,d] by BLAS in Fortran

Tags: fortran, blas

Related question
[How to speed up reshape in higher rank tensor contraction by BLAS in Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66253618/how-to-speed-up-reshape-in-higher-rank-tensor-contraction-by-blas-in-fortran)

Suppose I have a contraction
`A[a,b] * B[c,b,d] = C[a,c,d]` (the dummy index `b` is in middle of tensor `B`, which looks tricky)
and I would like to use `DGEMM` for it.

What I can do is

1. reshape `B[c,b,d]` into `B2[b,c,d]`
2. use the method in [How to speed up reshape in higher rank tensor contraction by BLAS in Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66253618/how-to-speed-up-reshape-in-higher-rank-tensor-contraction-by-blas-in-fortran) to evaluate `A[a,b] * B2[b,c,d] = C[a,c,d]`

Reshape can take a bit time. (If the target were `C[c,a,d]`, I need one more shape). Is there more efficient approach?

Comment: First guess I'd keep it simple - A(a,b)*B(c,b) is a matrix times matrix transpose, and then there are d of them. I suspect this will work pretty well unless a, b, c, d are all very small - how big are they typically?

Comment: Yes, IanBush's method is likely the best. You just need to call `dgemm` with `transa="N"` and `transb="T"`. This may even be faster than a non-transposed matrix multiplication.

Comment: Depending on the matrix sizes you might want to parallelize the `d` loop. For smaller matrices I'd also time `dgemm` vs. intrinsic matmul/transpose, e.g. `C(:,:,d) = matmul(A, transpose(B(:,:,d)))`.

Comment: Yes, I considered //ising the d loop as well but it all depends on the matrix sizes - I have access to machines with 128 cores in a node currently, and that number is only going to increase. In practice some nested //isation, some in the matmult, some in the d loop, might be the best way to go. But this is far down the line and well into hand waving land.

Comment: Typically 30~70 for `a,b,c,d`. There are some other higher-dimensional arrays. What will be the transpose on a three dimensional array? (sorry I don't know) `transpose(B(:,:,d)` will only transpose the first two indices?

Comment: @AlphaF20 `B(:,:,d)` is a _two_-dimensional array and `transpose` works as usual. The sizes of 30~70 sound quite small and `matmul` could be as fast as `dgemm`. Just time your code.