# BLAS tensor contractions for two indexes together

Tags: fortran, tensor, blas, contractions

I want to calculate D[a,d] = A[a,b,c] * B[b,c,d].

Method I: reshape A[a,b,c] => C1[a,e], B[b,c,d] => C2[e,d], e = b*c

Method II: directly call dgemm. This is a run-time error.

" na, nb, nc, nd ?
2 3 5 7
Time for reshaping method   2.447600000000000E-002

Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 10 was incorrect on entry to DGEMM .
Time for straight  method   1.838800000000000E-002
Difference between result matrices    5.46978468774136  "

Question: Can we contract two indexes together by BLAS?

The following only works for one index.
[How to speed up reshape in higher rank tensor contraction by BLAS in Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66253618/how-to-speed-up-reshape-in-higher-rank-tensor-contraction-by-blas-in-fortran)

```
Program reshape_for_blas

  Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only :  wp => real64, li => int64

  Implicit None

  Real( wp ), Dimension( :, :, : ), Allocatable :: a
  Real( wp ), Dimension( :, :, : ), Allocatable :: b
  Real( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: c1, c2
  Real( wp ), Dimension( :, :    ), Allocatable :: d
  Real( wp ), Dimension( :, :    ), Allocatable :: e

  Integer :: na, nb, nc, nd, ne
  
  Integer( li ) :: start, finish, rate

  Write( *, * ) 'na, nb, nc, nd ?'
  Read( *, * ) na, nb, nc, nd
  ne = nb * nc
  Allocate( a ( 1:na, 1:nb, 1:nc ) ) 
  Allocate( b ( 1:nb, 1:nc, 1:nd ) ) 
  Allocate( c1( 1:na, 1:ne ) ) 
  Allocate( c2( 1:ne, 1:nd ) ) 
  Allocate( d ( 1:na, 1:nd ) ) 
  Allocate( e ( 1:na, 1:nd ) ) 

  ! Set up some data
  Call Random_number( a )
  Call Random_number( b )

  ! With reshapes
  Call System_clock( start, rate )
  c1 = Reshape( a, Shape( c1 ) )
  c2 = Reshape( b, Shape( c2 ) )
  Call dgemm( 'N', 'N', na, nd, ne, 1.0_wp, c1, Size( c1, Dim = 1 ), &
                                            c2, Size( c2, Dim = 1 ), &
                                    0.0_wp, e, Size( e, Dim = 1 ) )
  Call System_clock( finish, rate )
  Write( *, * ) 'Time for reshaping method ', Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate
  
  ! Direct
  Call System_clock( start, rate )
  Call dgemm( 'N', 'N', na, nd, ne, 1.0_wp, a , Size( a , Dim = 1 ), &
                                            b , Size( b , Dim = 1 ), &
                                            0.0_wp, d, Size( d, Dim = 1 ) )
  Call System_clock( finish, rate )
  Write( *, * ) 'Time for straight  method ', Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate

  Write( *, * ) 'Difference between result matrices ', Maxval( Abs( d - e ) )

End Program reshape_for_blas
```

Comment: Parameter number 10 is the leading dimension of the b array in the second call to dgemm, i.e. effectively C2 in your reformulation. You thus have an incorrect leading dimension. I suggest you re-read the text of the duplicate to your previous question, think what you are actually doing in your contraction, and see if you can work out what this parameter should be. You'll learn a lot more sorting it out yourself.

Comment: Thanks.@Ian Bush I finally understand it. The second dgemm should be like this: 'Call dgemm( 'N', 'N', na, nd, ne, 1.0_wp, a , Size( a , Dim = 1 ), & b , ne , & 0.0_wp, d, Size( d, Dim = 1 ) )'